# Store timestamp each users in sorted set Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a little code:

**Add ID:**

```
 redis.zadd('onlineusers', time, id, function (err, response) {
    //TODO
  });
```

Is a correct way to save current timestamp user with him **ID**?

**Delete ID by KEY:**

```
db.zrem('onlineusers', data.id);
```

Also, how to get multiple values from sorted set by keys: `1,2,3`

Comment: http://redis.io/commands/zrange

Comment: Can you tell me, what is a sintax command in redis-node for `sismember`

Comment: do you mean `redis.sismember('myset', mymember, function (e, result) {...})`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is a correct way to save current timestamp user with him ID?

Yes

You can get the scores of multiple values using multi.

```
function getScores(setKey, values, callback) {
    var multi = db.multi();
    for(var i=0; i<values.length; ++i) {
        multi.zscore(setKey, values[i]);
    }
    multi.exec(callback);
}
```

Usage

```
getScores('onlineusers', [1,2,3], function(err, scores) { 
    console.log(err, scores);
});
```